# Explicitly set colours of the boxplot in ploltly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

I am using `plotly express` to plot `boxplot` as shown below:

```
px.box(data_frame=df, 
       y="price", 
       x="products",
       points="all")
```

However, the boxpots of the products shown up with the same colours. They are four products. I would like to colour each with a different colour, using an additional paramter `color_discrete_sequence` does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using `plotly.express.data.tips()` as an example dataset and am creating a new column called `mcolour` to show how we can use an additional column for coloring. See below;

```
## packages
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

```
## example dataset:
df = px.data.tips()

## creating a new column with colors
df['mcolour'] = np.where(
     df['day'] == "Sun" , 
    '#636EFA', 
     np.where(
        df['day'] == 'Sat', '#EF553B', '#00CC96'
     )
)
```

```
## plot
fig = px.box(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color="mcolour")
fig = fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

So, as you see, you can simply assign colors based on another column using `color` argument in `plotly.express.box()`.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. A straightforward solution would be to simply provide the desired color codes in `color_discrete_sequence`. For example,  `fig = px.box(df, x="day", y="total_bill", color="sex", color_discrete_sequence=[ "#FF7F0E", "#00CC96"])`

Comment: @PyLabour if you provide a reproducible example, I can investigate further, considering that your solution is essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add, before plotting, this parameter setting (as part of an effective solution) in order to align the (indeed!) newly colored box plots correctly.

```
fig.update_layout(boxmode = "overlay")
```

The boxmode setting "overlay" brings the plot back to the normal layout, that is seemingly being overridden (as setting "group") after having set the color.

In the plotly help it says about boxmode:

> "Determines how boxes at the same location coordinate are displayed on
> the graph. If 'group', the boxes are plotted next to one another
> centered around the shared location. If 'overlay', the boxes are
> plotted over one another [...]"

Hope this helps! R